# MacBook Pro 10-15s delay on power button

Tags: macos, startup

I have very weird problem. When I want to power on my macbook pro after I press the button I need to wait 10-15s to see Apple Logo icon. It is so frustrating every time I need to restart my mac I need to wait 10-15s on black screen and later everything is working perfect. I have read questions on official apple website and they suggest that in this kind of problem I need to reset PRAM, SMC and select bootable disk to MacOS. After that I am still getting this problem.

I have done a clean instalation too and I am still getting this problem. Thanks for any help

Macbook PRO 2018 15,1 and I am running on latest Catalina

Comment: The Apple logo during boot is simply an indicator that your Mac found the boot volume and is booting.  Before it boots it needs to POST (Power On Self Test) where it does a quick check to make sure things are good before booting.  If it's taking a while to get through this, you may have a hardware issue or an issue with your boot partition.  Start with [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) (Hold `D` while booting).  Also try booting while holding `Opt` so that it immediately launches the boot manager.  How quickly does that come up?

Comment: All tests passed, actually I have upgraded iOS to Big Sur and problem has gone... Weird

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this exact same issue. Hardware test said I had no issues. After about another two weeks of use, my internal ssd went dead, and i had to replace it. After replacement, all is speedy again. So if its not a corrupt efi or boot partition, i would suspect you might have a failing hard drive.